# Live account to Paypal Digital Goods

Tags: php, paypal

I have already integrated Paypal Digital Goods Express Checkout payment to my webapp, using a sandbox test account. I have followed this wizard: http://goo.gl/sCmT8i

Now I need to put it live. But I am not able to create a live account for my Paypal application.

In the Paypal Developer Admin, I have the menu "REST API eligibility", where I check that I can make PayPal payments and Log In with PayPal. Then I see a link `"Enable live Credentials"`, that shows me this message:

> Note: Direct credit card processing and payment tokens are not available for you when using REST APIs. Your live credentials are inoperable for direct credit card processing and payment tokens for your country but, your test credentials are enabled for sandbox testing.

Does it means that I cannot have a live account? I am in the wrong place? The PayPal docs did not help me at all.

Comment: i believe its a county specific limitation, there are many of thoses when dealing with international payment gateways.

Comment: This is bad man. This payment mode was suggested by a Paypal contact here in Brazil. Does anyone know where I can check the availability of it?

Answer (score 1):

You can still process PayPal payments via our REST API's when that message is displayed, but you cannot process direct credit card transactions with it.

In other words:

- [This works](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/web/accept-paypal-payment/)
- [This doesn't](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/accept-credit-cards/)